# Suwon is on the itinerary while travelling through South Korea. What should I do there and what is Suwon known for?

Tags: activities, south-korea

I need help in deciding what to do in Suwon during my stop there on a trip to South Korea. I've done a little research, however I'm curious if anyone has more experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are in Suwon, the very first thing you should do is to try suwon galbi. Suwon is one of the best places in South Korea to try galbi. Also, don't forget to visit Hwasong, a fortress which was built after imjin japanse invasion.
There is also a famous amusement park in Korea near suwon called, 'everland'. 
Plan on spending about 2-3 days to look around and try things I suggested above and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks! Are all of these activities pretty economical?

Comment: Galbi would cost around $30, and visiting Hwasong won't cost you anything as it is open tourist attraction. Everland would cost you about $40 for daily pass.

Comment: I love walled cities and only found out about Hwasong fortress about two days before leaving Seoul after being there for about seven weeks. Sadly both last days were very rainy so I didn't get to visit. I believe that Everland has the reputation of being Korea's unofficial knockoff of Disneyland, just like Japan had Dreamland until that country was bestowed with its very own genuine Disneyland not so long ago.